# True and False in Predicate logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

**The sentences below are either true no matter how P is interpreted or False for some interpretations of P. Decide which one fits into which category.**

**(a) (∃x P(x)) ⇒ (∀y P(y))**

**(b) ∀x (P(x) ⇒ ∃y P(y))**

**(c) ∃x (P(x) ⇒ (∀y P(y))**

**(d) ∀x∃y (P(x) ⇒ P(y))**

**(e) ∃y∀x (P(x) ⇒ P(y))**

So I thought a) would be false because if P(x) simply exists, it does not necessarily imply that P(y) exists for all y.

For b) I thought it would be true because it is already stated that the sentence applies for all x and therefore it must be true for all interpretations of P.

For c), I thought it was false because I did not think that simply because x existed implied that y existed for all cases.

I thought both d) and e) would be true because as all long as both exist for all y and x, order didn't matter and the implication would simply stand.

However, I am not sure about my reasoning for either and it is very likely I have gotten many wrong.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

A.  Give an example.  Try something like P(x) for x is odd.
B.  True.
C.  True.  There are two cases:  for all x, P(x) and its negation.
D.  True.  For each x, let y = x.
E.  True.  There are two cases:  for all x, not P(x) and its negation.

Order of quantifiers makes a big difference.